# permanecer en un viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Estoy realizando un iniciar sesión para *iOS*. El problema es que tengo 2 `viewController`, de los cuales, el primero tiene 2 `textField` (usuario y contraseña) y un botón (Ingresar), y el segundo, solo tiene una etiqueta `Ingresaste` y ambos conectados por un `Segue`.

El primer `viewController` tiene este código:

```
@IBAction func ingresarButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let txtcorreo = correoText.text!
    let txtclave = claveText.text!
    let url = URL(string: "webservice")
    let postString = "txtcorreo=\(txtcorreo)&txtclave=\(txtclave)"
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    let tarea = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){
        (datos, respuesta, error) in
        if error != nil{
            print(error!)
        }else{
            do{
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: datos!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String:Any]
                let estado = json["estado"] as! Int

                if estado == 200 {
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "usuarioLogueado")
                    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginSegue", sender: self)
                }else{
                    print("usuario no existe")
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }

            }catch{
                print("No funciona JSON")
            }
        }
    }
    tarea.resume()
}
```

El problema es que cada vez que lleno los campos erróneamente el segundo `viewController` aparece por 5 segundos y después regresa al primero.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que no aparezca el segundo `viewController` cuando lleno los campos mal y solo me muestre un mensaje de **Usuario no existe**?

Comment: Si estas seguro que la rama del else es que el usuario no existe, pon ahi el mensaje, pero para que haces un dismiss si no tiene que salir de ningún controlador?

Comment: el detalle es que si no le pongo el dismiss la aplicación lo reconoce como correcto y se queda en la siguiente ventana

Comment: Pues lo mismo tienes el error en lo que te devuelve. El performSegue se supone que solo lo hace si es correcto porque estado es 200

Comment: No tendrás conectado el `segue` al botón? Da la impresión que tu botón no sólo tiene el `IBOutlet` conectado, sino que también le has conectado el `segue` e independientemente del codigo en tu `IBAction` siempre avanza a la siguiente pantalla...

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes conectado el Segue desde el Botón, como menciona jdev tal vez es lo que te esta dando problemas... te recomiendo que la conexión la hagas desde el icono del viewcontroller para crear el Segue... como en la imagen a continuación tengo señalado el icono y luego dejas Press ctrl y lo colocas en el VC que quieras.. saludos!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Podrias utilizar una funcion como esta, la cual agrega un bloque de codigo el cual espera hasta que la consulta HTTP es completada y luego procede con las siguientes funciones dependiendo de la respuesta obtenida:

```
private func login_Servidor()
    {
        let postString = "txtcorreo=Usuario" +
                         "&txtclave=Clave"

        self.login(parametros: postString)
        { codigo_respuesa in

            if let codigo = codigo_respuesa
            {
                if codigo == 200
                {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async
                    {
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "usuarioLogueado")
                        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginSegue", sender: self)
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    print("Usuario no existe")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async
                    {
                        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                print("No se logro completar la operacion")
            }
        }
    }

    private func login(parametros: String,
                       completion: @escaping(Int?) -> ())
    {
        var codigo_respuesta: Int?

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "webservice")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = parametros.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)
        {(datos, respuesta, error) in

            if error != nil
            {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error")
            }
            else
            {
                if let url_response = respuesta as? HTTPURLResponse
                {
                    if url_response.statusCode == 200
                    {//Operacion exitosa
                        do
                        {
                            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: datos!,
                                                                        options: .mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
                            if let estado = json["estado"] as? Int
                            {
                                if estado == 200
                                {
                                    codigo_respuesta = estado
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            print("No se pudo convertir el JSON")
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {//Error en la consulta HTTP
                        print("El servidor envio un codigo de respuesa: \(url_response.statusCode)")
                    }
                }
            }
            completion(codigo_respuesta)
        }.resume()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu boton debe estar conectado al segue, lo que debes hacer es conectar el ViewController (no el botón), al llamar al botón hacer la validación y solo en caso de que sea correcto llamar al Segue.

También debes sacar ese dismiss, ya que ahora, al no irte a la otra pantalla intentarías hacer un dismiss del primer ViewController.

Tambien debes asegurarte de no estar haciendo la pantalla en el hilo principal, ya que vas a dejar la app pegada.

Y por último, como consejo, no hagas requests desde el ViewController, crear una clase para esto, será más fácil mantenerlo o reemplazarlo.